# How do I fix connection manager error that causes the package to fail in production?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have created an SSIS package and it works great on my dev machine. But, when I try to run it on the production server, it errors out on me.

Here is the error:

```
Error: The AcquireConection method call to the connection manager 
"DestinationConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.
```

I have figured out the cause, but am not sure how to get it fixed. The password isn't in the connection string. But I have set the password in the SSIS project. For some reason though, when I deploy and run this on the production server, it won't run since the password isn't part of the connection string.

Is there some setting in the SSIS project that I need to change in order to get this to work right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable the password by setting the ProtectionLevel in the package properties to DontSaveSensitive.

I also recommend moving the connection string to a package variable and make an expression on the connection.  Enable package configurations.

Then you are free to change the connection and to use integrated security or not without changing the package.  You can either put the connection string in the configuration or then provide it on the command line.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick and also enabled a bit more flexibility.